# Core Data: Observing all changes on Entity of certain type

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I would like to be notified whenever an entity of a certain type is added/changed/removed.  I know that this is possible by adding an observer to the `managedObjectContext`, but then I have to search the three sets that are returned to see if they contain an object of that type.  I could use `filteredSetUsingPredicate`, but it seems inefficient to do an O(n) operation three times every time there is a change.  Is there another more efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Don't confuse entities with managed objects. Entities are abstractions akin to classes and they are not added or removed to context. Managed objects are the concrete instances that represent entities and they are inserted, updated and deleted in contexts.

Answer (score 5):

It *seems* inefficient? Based on what testing and observation? How do you think NSArrayController works (hint - read up on Cocoa Bindings)? :-) Sure, with a SQLite store type you get in-database filtering for fetches but what about in-memory changes to the objects?

If I were in your position, I'd wire it up and performance test it with what I imagine is a reasonable worst-case scenario that a real-life user is likely to encounter.

If you find performance is indeed lacking, it's best you post a separate question describing your data model, the reasons you need to observe all changes to all instances of a given entity, and where Instruments says the performance sink is happening.